# Ubuntu App on Windows 10 : No video0 mount found

Tags: windows, video, jupyter, stream

I am trying to create a video stream on jupyter and getting this error:

> VIDEOIO ERROR: V4L: can't open camera by index 0

When I check `/mnt`, there's no video device.

How can I mount the cam available on my laptop in the Ubuntu app on Windows 10?

Comment: The Ubuntu app in Windows 10 is command line only. It has no video dinner, no GUI. It can't display any video.

Comment: Yeah, but jupyter should be able to access the device, right?
Since Jupyter UI is being opened on underlying windows.